# Angular6 - Reactive Forms - Cannot programmatically set select option when using objects and [selected] binding

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

Seriously stumped here. I have two reactive forms in an Angular project.

Both have a select control with options stored in class variables.

One form uses simple option strings for employee options, as in:

`["Dan Smith", "Mark Johnson", etc.]`

The other form uses objects, as in:

```js
[
  {
    value: "Dan Smith",
    selected: false,
    hidden: false
  },
  ...
]
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nks51y

In the example I have buttons for adding new random options, and setting a random selected option.

The buttons work on the form which uses simple strings, but don't work with the form using objects {}.

Additionally, the default value isn't set with the object form.

I know I'm missing something, but can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code:

1. you should **never** set the `selected` attribute of the select element. The whole point of the binding is that the option that is selected is the one set as the value of the form control. The model is the source of truth, not the view
2. The selected value (i.e. the value of the FormControl) is an object: the employee object itself. But the `ngValue` used in the template is `name.value`, i.e. a string which is the value of the employee object. An employee object can't be === to its `value` property.

So the code should be:

```
<select formControlName="employeeName">
  <option *ngFor="let employee of employeeNameObjectOptions" [ngValue]="employee" [hidden]="employee.hidden">
    {{ employee.value }}
  </option>                
</select>
```

Note that I chose to rename `name` to `employee` since that's what the variables refereces: an employee, not a name. Good naming helps a lot to figure out mistakes.

Your fixed demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pundfg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: JB Nizet, thank you for taking the time answer this clearly, thoroughly, and give an example. Could you touch a little on the use [compareWith] ? In searching for a solution to this problem I found multiple references to it, but don't quite understand the need for it.

Comment: It allows using something other than strict equality (i.e. `===`) to test if the value of the option should be considered equal to the value of the form control. Imagine you get an object using an http request, containing the employee of the month. And you make another http request to get all the employees of the company to populate the select box. Even though the employee of the month is, functionally, one of the employees of the company, they're different JavaScript objects. compareWith can be used, for example, to consider two employees equal if they have the same ID.

Answer (score 2):

The `ngValue` for your select option is a string `[ngValue]="name.value"` and type does not match when you are setting an object to it.

```
<option *ngFor="let name of employeeNameObjectOptions" [selected]="name.selected" [ngValue]="name" [hidden]="name.hidden">
        {{ name.value }}
</option>
```